# Show that the implication $x ≥ 5 ⇒ x^2 ≥ 25$ is true.

Tags: logic

I really really don't know where to start on problems like this one. Show the implication $x ≥ 5 ⇒ x^2 ≥ 25 $ , I have googled for an hour but I haven't even found one similar problem on the internet. I would deeply appreciate any links on how to solve this problems.

Comment: What assumptions or axioms about the real numbers do you have to start from? You can't usually solve real mathematics problems by looking on the internet. By the way: you have been on this site for a month now but still rely on other people to format your mathematics correctly. Please learn and use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what do you know? what are you allowed to use?

Comment: It's of course a trivial implication ... which makes one wonder: "if I have to prove *that*, what other trivial things do I need to prove in order to prove that?"  So, I can understand why you are utterly baffled by a question like this ... I would be too! Still, were you maybe told what *can* you assume?  Are you given any kind of axioms?

Answer (score 2):

One basic property of inequalities is that $a\ge b, c>0 \implies ac\ge bc$.

Using this, we have $x \ge 5 > 0 \implies x^2 \ge 5x \ge 5\cdot 5 =25$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x\ge5 $ and $x^2<25$. Thus $(x-5)(x+5)<0$  hence one of the two $(x+5),(x-5)$ must be negative but $x\ge5\implies x+5>x-5\ge 0$ . A contradiction. So $x^2\ge 25$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y:=x-5$, so that $x=y+5$, and $x^2 = (y+10)y+25$.

Therefore, $(x\geq 5)\to(x^2\geq 25)$ is true if and only if $(y\geq 0)$ implies $((y+10)y\geq 0)$ is true.

Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^2-25=(x-5)(x+5)$. $     $

Answer (score 0):

Since $x > 5$, then $10(x-5)>0$

$x^2 = [5+(x-5)]^2 = 25 + 10(x-5) + (x-5)^2 > 25$